# HTML page (Only with Tables, no css allowed)

Tags: html

I am trying to create a page as shown in picture. Now only tables are allowed and no css. I am having difficulty in understanding how to achieve as it is in original image. Any help please?
[image]

This is what I have written

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
<table height="350" width="773" background="bg.jpg" >
<tr><td><h1 align="right">Welcome to Full Moom Site</h1></td></tr>
<tr><td><h3 align="center">Music Company Full Moon</h3></td></tr>
<tr><td><p align="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vulputate, odio ut auctor porta, quam urna convallis leo, ac ultricies felis mi eget mi. Pellentesque consequat nisl et metus tempor sodales. Quisque ultrices metus consectetur sem placerat eget molestie ipsum gravida. Duis scelerisque augue sed sem venenatis id congue mauris vehicula. </p></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you might have forgotten to post the picture you're referring to.

Comment: I have posted it and it is visible, you can't see the first image on top? there's just one picture which I am referring and it's on top

Comment: @derekerdmann I see a picture.  @ Zai Why do you have to have "no css"?  is it because you can't link to CSS?  If so, why not use CSS inside the page `<style> ... </style>`

Comment: @rockinthesixstring I need to achieve this without CSS, it's just compulsory :(

Comment: I can't see any pictures... IE7 problem on StackOverflow, perhaps?  Asking about it on Meta.

Comment: Ok here's the link if you can't see above http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=6omk9v&s=4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't get me to do the work for you :-) , but I'll offer up this advice. You'll need to slice up your background image into four parts, use `colspan` and `rowspan` on your `<td>` and `<tr>` tags, and `border="0"` on the `<table>` tag to get it to work. Here's an example, including a possible grid for your table layout. You'll need to move your navigation down a little bit; otherwise, you'll need a fifth slice for the left end of the blue arc.

[image: example slices]

Comment: I’d suggest combining 1 and 4 into one image.